# MySQL Query Involving 3 Tables And 2 Databases, Can't Get Correct Columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using the following query to pull data from 3 tables. 2 are in the same database and 1 in a different database. Basically I have recipes in one table, and I'm using the `recipieToCountry` table to connect to the `countries` table so I know what country a recipe belongs to.

```
$contentQuery = $page->dbf->query("
  SELECT *
    FROM recipes, recipeToCountry, content.countries
    WHERE recipes.id = recipeToCountry.recipeId 
      AND recipeToCountry.countryId = content.countries.id
      AND content.countries.origId = '$country'
 ");
```

The problem I'm running into is when I call `$content->title` it returns the title from `countries` when I want the title from `recipies`. My understanding is `SELECT *` is the issue, so I tried to change the query to this:

```
SELECT title, description, approved, active, id, recipeId, countryId 
  FROM recipes, recipeToCountry
  WHERE recipes.id = recipeToCountry.recipeId 
UNION 
SELECT id, origId, null, null, null, null, null 
  FROM content.countries
  WHERE content.countries.origId = 1 
    AND recipeToCountry.countryId = content.countries.id
```

Unfortunately this query has an error, and I'm unsure how to fix it. When I removed the last `AND` the `UNION` doesn't seem to work as well. Any ideas on what changes I could make to get the correct columns?

Comment: `SELECT recipies.title, ...`  When you have column names that exist in multiple tables that are part of your query, you must prefix the column name with the table name (or table alias).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple JOINs should work well:

```
select r.*, c.*
  from recipes r
  join repiceToCountry rc on r.id = rc.recipeId
  join content.countries c on c.id = rc.countryId
  where c.origId = '$country'
```

You must make sure you have `SELECT` privileges on the other database.

Also, you can replace `r.*, c.*` by the specific columns you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a habit a long time ago of always putting the table alias/name before every field in the query.  This way you can modify the query later on without worrying about fields names that conflict when you add tables to the query. I also prefer joins to multiple FROM tables. (It's easier to see the logic)

I would change your first query to this:

```
SELECT r.*, c.country /* any other fields in country besides title */
FROM recipes as r
LEFT JOIN recipeToCountry as rtc ON rtc.recipeId = r.id
LEFT JOIN content.countries as c ON c.id = rtc.countryId
WHERE c.origId = '$country'
```

You can leave the word "as" out to make it look a little cleaner, but I leave it in there to show what's happening a little better.